# How to increase negative space / improve scaling of vector graphic?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I'm fairly new to Illustrator. I bought a vector graphic of a wolf for this logo I designed (see screenshot with  purple on white logo). It looks good when it is quite large, but if I scale down the logo then my wolf doesn't look as good anymore - you can barely see his eye and somehow his fur looks a bit too bulky and out of balance for the image (see a screenshot with t-shirt design).

I was wondering if it is possible to somehow **increase the negative space** in the wolf graphic without screwing things up, so that the purple (or gold on the t-shirt) becomes thinner leaving more of the negative space. I am concerned about manipulating individual anchors, as I think I'll make it look weird.

Or if you could suggest how to improve on the wolf graphic otherwise so it looks nice and crisp when scaled down - it'd be most appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just our of curiosity, do you need to use those colors in the second one? It is mainly the low(er) contrast that is affecting the way the graphic interacts with the background. Did you try (just for now) with a lighter shade on black? If you look at the hair, for example, you can see the brown and dark grey are just not contrasting enough.

Comment: Are you limited to a single color? Unfortunately I don't think you will be able to counter the effect of the negative space the graphic is creating. Perhaps reducing the space may help. A lot going on here though. The actual shape of the graphic is of a bear. And the graphic on the shirt looks like a badger. Try reducing the chest thickness and the large negative space.

Comment: Also ensure you have scale stroke and effect turned on.
Menu > Object > Transform > Scale > Check - Scale stroke and effect. This will retain the integrity of the vectors when scaling.

Comment: Yisela, thank you. I noticed the same problem when I make the logo any light color, even the background is very contrasting. Somehow dark on light looks good, but light on dark gets not so good.

Comment: For it to work well reversed, and be perceived clearly, you need to reverse the wolf head -- making light areas dark and dark areas light. Of course, that means you'll need to rethink the circle and banner as well.

Comment: @Scott - thank you!!!! I just tried and I think that helped a lot. If you have any other suggestions - would be most thankful :)  I really want to make this looking great!!

Comment: I'm glad that helped. The only other thing I'd suggest, without seeing the file directly, is to possibly increase the size of the pupil so it's slightly more prominent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wanted to let everyone know - the issue was solved thanks to @Scott:

"For it to work well reversed, and be perceived clearly, you need to reverse the wolf head -- making light areas dark and dark areas light. Of course, that means you'll need to rethink the circle and banner as well. –  Scott Feb 13 at 8:25 "

After following this advise - I reversed the graphic's white space and it worked out perfectly on dark background! I'm attaching the t-shirt design with reversed logo :)

Thanks @Scott!

[image]

Comment: Glad I was able to assist. Shirt looks great! Thanks for sharing.